# How to sound a bell when the user clicks outside a modal window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The situation is simple. I have a main window with a Help - About menu.
When this menu item is clicked, a modal window is opened (let's say it's an About-window).
With `self.grab_set()` I disabled the main-window (although the modal window does flicker when you click the main title bar).
So far, so good.

**Here is the question:** I really like to sound a bell when the user clicks outside the modal window on the main window.

This is what I could find about grab_set(), really not that much:

- [effbot] ...a method called grab_set, which makes sure that no mouse or keyboard
  events are sent to the wrong window.
- [effbot] Routes all events for this application to this widget.
- [kite.com] A grab directs all events to this and descendant widgets in the application.
- [google books] grab_set() ensures that all of the application's events are sent to w until a corresponding call is made to grab_release ([Me:] or till the window is destroyed?)

I'm not quite sure how to understand this: does it mean you can handle an event on the main window within the modal window (like sounding my bell)?
So I tried things like:

`self.bind('<Button-1>', self.bell)`    Exception in Tkinter callback: _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name
  `parent.bind('<Button-1>', self.bell)`  Nothing happens

So, how to sound a bell like when clicked outside the modal window on the main window, like in so many other applications?

**Derived questions**:

- Is it still possible to cature events from the main window after using
  grab_set for the modal window?
- Is there a way to prevent the flickering?

I really like to understand this mysterious `grab_set()` method.

**Stripped code:**

```
import tkinter as tk

class About(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.geometry('200x150')

        #--- OK button
        btn_ok = tk.Button(self, text='OK', command=self.destroy)  # destroy with OK
        btn_ok.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        btn_ok.focus()                                             # destroy with spacebar

        #--- Make window modal
        self.grab_set()                 
        # self.wait_window()              # is this necessary in this case?
        # self.bind('<Button-1>', self.bell) ??? The question

class MenuBar(tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Menu.__init__(self)
        helpmenu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        helpmenu.add_command(label='About', command=lambda: About(parent))
        self.add_cascade(label='Help', menu=helpmenu)

class MainApp():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        parent.configure(background='#000000')
        parent.geometry('800x600')
        menubar = MenuBar(parent)
        parent.configure(menu=menubar)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The canonical documentation is here: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/grab.htm

Comment: Thanks for that, Bryan. I have to re-read it a few times, but at first sight it seems to me that it should be possible to capture events from the parent window within the modal window... somehow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set a grab, all button clicks will go to the window with the grab. You capture them the way you capture any other event. In the case of a button click you do that by binding a function to `<1>`.

It's important to know that a binding on a root window or a `Toplevel` window will apply to all widgets in that window. For example, binding to `self` in your code will fire even when you click on the "Ok" button. Therefore, the callback should probably only do work when the widget associated with the event is the same as the toplevel.

Example:

```
class About(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ...
        self.bind("<1>", self.capture_click)
        ...
    def capture_click(self, event):
        if event.widget == self:
            <your logic here>
```

In the case of wanting to know if the user clicked outside the window, you can use the coordinates of the event object to compare against the window to see if the click is inside or outside.

```
    def on_click(self, event):
        if event.widget == self:
            if (event.x < 0 or event.x > self.winfo_width() or
                event.y < 0 or event.y > self.winfo_height()):
                self.bell()
```

Comment: Wow, thanks Bryan! That IS something to think about! To be honest, I did saw something along these lines, but it was all in Java so I didn't get the details. I'm a little bit tired right now, but tomorrow I'll go through it line-by-line. High expectations ;-)

Comment: It's working! I was so close...! I don't think I need the `if event.widget == self` check, at least not in *this* case, but there will be more modal windows, so I keep it as a comment. Thanks a 1000 times!

Answer (score 2):

I found a second solution. Though my question was explicitly about using grab_set(), this method does the same for me: making the window as modal as possible and sound a bell.

Instead of using self.grab(), you can also disable the parent window:

```
parent.attributes('-disabled', True)
```

Of course it needs to be enabled again when the OK button is clicked (and when the windows is closed with the [X] close control. However, my original About-window has no window decoration). The command for the OK-button becomes:

```
btn_ok = tk.Button(self, text='OK', command=lambda: self.closeme(parent))
```

...which calls the `closeme` function:

```
def closeme(self, parent):
    parent.attributes('-disabled', False)
    self.destroy()
```

The bell sounds automatically when clicking a disabled window.

**Method 1:** Keeps you in full control of the main window but does not 'freeze' the main window: you can still move it around.

**Method 2:** Completely freezes the main window, but if it happens to be (partially) covered by another window (not of this application), then you can only bring back to top using Alt+Tab (windows).

I'm sure I will use both techniques in the future depending on my needs.

Comment: In my (measly) opinion, this is the better answer. @Bryan Oakley's answer doesn't address the fact that binding to specific key/pointer events won't prevent others from firing which could cause all kinds of problems in a sufficiently complex application. This answer successfully blocks all input to the parent window, which should be the goal of a modal window.