# Tkinter - How can I improve the "grab_set()" method behavior?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a simple code in which we  have a main window with two buttons. the first one opens a new window, the second one opens a message box.

when I open the message box window, I can't letterally interact with the main window in any way, if I click on it the system bell plays and the message box flashes. I would like to replicate the same behhaviour the other window, but how? when I apen it I can't interact with the main window because of the `grab_set()` method, but in this case no system bell plays, no flash style appears, and after all I can still move the main window via its title bar and I don't like it. how can I replicate the same behaviour seen with the message box, in the new window?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox

class MainWindow:   
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent=Tk()
        self.parent.title("Main Window")
        self.parent.configure(background="#f0f0f0")
        self.parent.geometry("300x200+360+200")

        self.NewWindowButton=ttk.Button(self.parent, text="Open the new Window", command=lambda: NewWindow(self.parent))
        self.MsgBoxButton=ttk.Button(self.parent, text="Open a Message Box", command=lambda: messagebox.showerror("Error", "Error"))        
        self.NewWindowButton.pack()
        self.MsgBoxButton.pack()

        self.parent.mainloop()

class NewWindow:   
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.window, self.parent=Toplevel(parent), parent
        self.window.title("New Window")
        self.window.configure(background="#f0f0f0")
        self.window.geometry("300x200+360+200")
        self.window.resizable (width=False, height=False)
        self.window.grab_set()


def main():
    app=MainWindow()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

below you can see my software behavior in Windows 10 (it's a gif image):

http://www.imagebam.com/image/ac4a4a1347175889

Comment: When I run your code on OSX I get exactly the same behavior for both the messagebox and toplevel. In both cases I can still drag around the main window, and in both cases I cannot click any buttons in the main window.

Comment: Hola Bryan. I just added a gif in my question. currently I tried my code only on Windows 10, and as you can see the `grab_set()` method has a different behavior than the code used for the message box. I don't have the same behavior for both windows. the message box blocks the main window, plays the system bell, and flashes. the other window doesn't do none of these things. how can I solve the issue?

Comment: You didn't set the `master=` argument, therefore the `Message(Dialog)` are using `root` as parent. But, you can't set multiple parents. You have to simulate it using this approach: [how-to-sound-a-bell-when-the-user-clicks-outside-a-modal-window/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62395920)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows, you can try:

- call `attributes('-disabled', 1)` to disable the parent window
- set the toplevel as transient window of parent
- call `wait_window()` to wait for the toplevel closed/destroyed
- call `attributes('-disabled', 0)` to enable the parent window

```py
class NewWindow:   
    def __init__(self, parent):
        try:
            parent.attributes('-disabled', 1) # disable the parent
            self.window, self.parent = Toplevel(parent), parent
            self.window.title("New Window")
            self.window.configure(background="#f0f0f0")
            self.window.geometry("300x200+360+200")
            self.window.resizable (width=False, height=False)
            self.window.transient(parent)
            self.window.grab_set()
            parent.wait_window(self.window) # wait for current window to close
        finally:
            # enable the parent
            parent.attributes('-disabled', 0)
```

Comment: Not sure why, but when I call tk.grab_set() on the tk.Tk() instance window it works perfectly fine, but when I use the same grab_set() on it's child (tk.Toplevel instance) it doesn't. Thanks for your answer with the `attributes` tho, it works for me!