# Tkinter: Detecting a running process and locking all the other buttons while one process is running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a Tkinter GUI, my Tkinter application have several functionalities it plots graphs also when I click on the plot button then one matplotlib window opens, but I want till the user don't close this matplotlib window he is not allowed to click on any other button if he clicks also then it should not do anything and prompt the user that please close current window. Not only for matplotlib if the user has opened one window so he should not be allowed to open another window till he closes the current window that he has opened and prompt should come to please close current window, Is there any way in python for the same that we can detect that any current window is opened or not ?

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('X values')
plt.ylabel('Y axis')
plt.plot()
```

this above process is triggered when i click on plot button but I want that till user has opened this window of matplotlib and not closes it he is not allowed to trigger any other process by clicking on other button , so my main problem is that how to know in tkinter that this matplotlib plot is opened , because then only I will be to able to disable other window?

Comment: Can we also know that if we have plotting option in tkinter window and we want to know that any matlotlib process is running or not but my matplotlib plot is not incoperated in tinter it's just called through a button which is there in my tkinter window?

Comment: Please give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I tried to do it

Comment: Should the last line `plt.plot()` be `plt.show()`? Is the code inside a function?

Comment: yes it is inside the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the main window (assume it is named `root`) using `root.attributes('-disabled', 1)` before opening the plot window, and re-enable the main window using `root.attributes('-disabled', 0)` after the plot window is closed.

```
def open_plot_window():
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.xlabel('X values')
    plt.ylabel('Y axis')
    # disable the main window
    root.attributes('-disabled', 1) 
    # setup a callback to re-enable the main window if the plot window is closed
    plt.connect('close_event', lambda _: root.attributes('-disabled', 0))
    # show the plot window
    plt.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Thank you very much can you add this thing to your answer that when I am clicking the the disabled window button then it is giving windows beep can you replace it with one message box saying please close current graph

Comment: Yes @acw1668 please add this to your answer which he has asked you

Comment: As the main window is disabled, it does not receive mouse click events.  Therefore it is hard to do what you want.

Comment: @acw1668 can you please tell if open another toplevel window then I want to lock the root window buttons is there any way

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62417582/tkinter-how-can-i-improve-the-grab-set-method-behavior/62420275#62420275) what you want?

Answer (score 0):

after matplotlib window opens you can disable all other buttons using disable method. you can enable it back by using enable methods. same applies for Close window button too.

Button is tkinter button var

```
root = Tk()
Quit = Button(root, text="Quit", width=12, command=close)
Quit.pack()
Quit["state"] = "disabled"
root.update()
time.sleep(2)
Quit["state"] = "normal"
root.update()
```

Comment: Thanks For answering but I want that when matplotlib  is opened then till the time user is analysing it till that point all the other buttons should be disabled , how to get that thing, and matplotlib graph is triggered not incoporated in tkinter window it is triggered just by clicking a one button

Comment: there is one module available in python named pyautogui. this will help you to detect whether the plot is available are not.once it detect window is available disable all.  and after it detecs no window enable back all