# Python Tkinter: Make popup window Modal Dialog?

Tags: python, tkinter, popupwindow

I want to make a pop up window that requires the user to interact with before using the main window, Modal Dialog. For example, the `messagebox` requires the user to answer the question before moving on. If the user tries to click on the original window, the `messagebox` flashes and plays the iconic error sound. This is what I want; I would use a `messagebox` but I want to add buttons, labels, widgets, etc...

How do you make a pop up window Modal Dialog?

Comment: The term you're looking for is "modal dialog"

Comment: Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62417582/tkinter-how-can-i-improve-the-grab-set-method-behavior) may help.